# Beamer: Change the colour of text one line at a time using itemize/alert

Tags: beamer, itemize, block, emphasis

I'm wanting to change the colour of the text in an itemized list one line at a time. This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

    \begin{theorem}
        $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
    \end{theorem}

\begin{block}

    \begin{proof}
        The proof is by contradiction.\pause

        \begin{itemize}
            \item \alert {item 1} \pause
            \item \alert {item 2} \pause
            \item \alert {item 3} \pause {Contradiction.}
        \end{itemize}

    \end{proof}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This highlights each line but then leaves it highlighted. How do I make the text revert back to the original colour so it is just the line in question that is highlighted?

Comment: Please do not post such fragments. Wrap a working document around it!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer New here. That better?

Comment: Yes, much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
      \item \alert<4>{item 1}
      \item item 2
      \item item 3 \only<4>{\alert{Contradiction}}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost. I need it to emphasise in colour one line at a time without the doubling up that the above leads to (emphasised then not emphasised). I also need item 1 and 'Contradiction' emphasised in colour at the same time at the end.

Comment: @serveoverice Sorry, but I don't understand what output you want, I don't see any doubling. Can you maybe draw a sketch or something how every slide should look like?

Comment: I need it to look like this: Item 1 in red -> Item 1 in normal, item 2 in red -> Item 1 in normal, item 2 in normal, item 3 in red -> Item 1 in red, item 2 in normal, item three in normal, Contradiction in red. Does that make sense?

Comment: @serveoverice like this?